# MIPS 3000 assembly, load and print 32-bit unsigned integer

Tags: assembly, printing, loading, mips, unsigned-integer

My program has to accept an input between between 0 and 2^32 or 4,294,967,295.

Which bit-wise 32 bytes should be able to do, but i'm overflowing into the negatives because i'm not sure how to make this an unsigned integer. I see that i have instructions that can do it via arithmetic, but what if i just want to load it into a register and print it? It always prints out the negative number right now.

Answer (score 1):

Whether the int is signed or unsigned should not matter for how it exists in the register.  Either way it is just a sequence of bits.  2^32 -1 = 0xFFFFFF.  If you interpret this as an unsigned integer, this is 4,294,967,295 or 2^32-1.  If you read it as a signed integer using two's complement, 0xFFFFFFFF is -1.  I would guess the problem is in your print command.  Try formatting your print output as unsigned.

Comment: I understand the first part of what your saying, but there doesn't appear to be a syscall for print unsigned integer for MIPS 3000, so not sure.

Comment: I suggest you show the code you are using to print the register.  I don't think this is about MIPS, but instead about your syscall to the OS and then what you do with the results.

Comment: @A.E.Drew: You could convert it to a string yourself (there must be dozens of questions here at SO for how to do that) and then use the print_string syscall (4).

Answer (score 1):

http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html

Try service call 36. That prints an unsigned int.